# Redis Key Expire Notification

Tags: java, java-8, redis

Is there a way to have a reliable notifications on key expiry in Redis. As I understood from the Redis documentation that key expiry notification is Redis is not reliable.

As per the documentation, Because Redis Pub/Sub is fire and forget currently there is no way to use this feature if your application demands reliable notification of events, that is, if your Pub/Sub client disconnects, and reconnects later, all the events delivered during the time the client was disconnected are lost.

Can someone suggest a way to have reliable key expiry notification through Redis or please suggest some other database or mechanism in Java to have data expiry and it's notification in order to perform additional operations on data on expiry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can improve the reliability of the notifications by having multiple clients subscribe to the keyspace expire notifications.

You can decouple the expire notification from the actual processing of the expired key, so you can manage to process them just once and also increase reliability by having the keyspace expire notification clients doing a simple queueing task. For this, you could use other data structures from Redis like sets or sorted sets (unique values), or even [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) with Consumer Groups.

Another option is to expire another key instead of the actual key. See [Event on key expire issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/6020). This is also helpful if you need the value of the expired key.

> Assuming your to-be-expired key is called 'foo', when you create it
>   don't expire it but rather create another key called 'foo:expire' and
>   set the TTL on it.
>
> ...
>   Upon getting an expiry event, fire the logic to store and remove the
>   "old" data ('foo')

On this approach, you can include logic to recover from missed notifications.

Comment: Thanks Leo. I have one more question here.  So what I understood is Redis Streams will allow us to stream messages using a producer and consumer/consumer groups. Is there a way that I can make Redis streams publish messages after x seconds or when it get expired.

Comment: My requirement here is after a certain amount of time, if no additional processing has been done on a key, it should be processed manually..

Comment: @BhupeshMathur, there is no way as of now to have automatic publication to a stream in Redis, this means you still need to have your own client subscribed to notifications and queueing to the Redis stream.